# app/Views/templates folder is not found in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Folder which is said to be where all the page templates located at could not be found with the following error: *cd: templates: No such file or directory.*

Will it be okay to re create the folder or is there something missing and need to be restored ?

Comment: Please don't hesitate to make your title clearer, eg 'Can I create folder app/Views/templates ?' and precise which version of CodeIgniter you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you **have to** create your folder `app/Views/templates/` and add your templates inside.

CodeIgniter does not create the folder automatically.